# Create multiple json objects using InMemoryDataService

Tags: angular

I am using InMemoryDataService to mock up a web server and I was able to return one json object successfully.

I am trying to use same to return multiple json objects and not sure how. 
Below is the code and would like to add one more object as 'inMemCall'

Thanks

```
export class InMemoryDataService {
  createDb() {  
    let inMemCall = [
    {
      category: 'Appetizers',
      details: [{
                 title: 'Item x1',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'testing World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x2',
                 price:'42.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x3',
                 price:'44.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                }]
    },
    {
      category: 'Soups and Salads',
      details: [{
                 title: 'Item x4',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x5',
                 price:'42.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x6',
                 price:'44.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                }]
    },
    {
      category: 'Entre',
      details: [{
                 title: 'Item x7',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x8',
                 price:'42.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                }]
    },
    {
      category: 'Sides',
      details: [{
                 title: 'Item x9',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                }]
    },
    {
      category: 'Deserts',
      details: [{
                 title: 'Item x10',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x11',
                 price:'42.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                }]
    },
    {
      category: 'Drinks',
      details: [{
                 title: 'Item x12',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x13',
                 price:'42.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },{
                 title: 'Item x14',
                 price:'40.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                },
                {
                 title: 'Item x15',
                 price:'42.00', 
                 description:'Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! '
                }]
    }
  ];
    return {inMemCall};
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show how are you returning the obj?

Comment: Please see below                                                                                                                       export class CartService {

 private cartsUrl = 'app/inMemCall1';
 constructor(private http: Http) { }
 
 getCartItems() {
  //return Promise.resolve(CARTITEMS);
  return this.http.get(this.cartsUrl)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json().data as CartItems[])
    .catch(this.handleError);
 }
 
 private handleError(error: any) {
  console.error('An error occurred', error);
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
 }
}

Comment: Issue resolved by returning 2 objects   like return {inMemCall, inMemCall1}